# What happens to Felix at the end of Thunderball?

Tags: james-bond, thunderball

At the end of Thunderball, when escaping the boat, Bond gives Felix a life ring and then pushes him off the boat. Bond and Domino then jump off the boat, before it hits some rocks and explodes.

A helicopter then drops a self-inflating lifeboat into the water, which Bond and Domino climb into, before being pulled away by a plane.

Why did they just leave Felix? Is it just because James Bond films always end up with him and the *Bond girl* together, and it would be weird if Felix was there with them?

Comment: Three really isn't a crowd ... [cough] [cough]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strangely this was on TV yesterday so I can answer.

It wasn't Felix Leiter at the end, it was Ladislav Kutze who was Largo's physicist. As he was a henchman, albeit one who redeemed himself by freeing Domino, we don't really care, so it's never resolved.

More info about him [here](http://www.jamesbondmm.co.uk/bond-villains/george-pravda).

Comment: This sounds like a good answer, but could you provide a script excerpt or screenshot to prove it?

Comment: thank you mark. @CrowTRobot he is correct. I googled a picture of Ladislav Kutze and that is the guy I was thinking of. I assumed it was Felix Leiter, because he helped free Domino and stop the bomb. There is a little more info on the following link. http://debrief.commanderbond.net/topic/28258-thunderball-ending/?p=503671

Comment: also the reason I asked this is because I had just watched it on TV :)